# Add leading zeroes to number in Dart

Tags: dart

I want to add some leading zeroes to a string. For example, the total length may be eight characters. For example:

```
123 should be 00000123
1243 should be 00001234
123456 should be 00123456
12345678 should be 12345678
```

What is an easy way to do this in Dart?

Answer (score 290, accepted):

[DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/6e24392642f8934b3e53)

```
void main() {
 print(123.toString().padLeft(10, '0'));
}
```

Comment: not working for negative numbers :)

Answer (score 54):

Using `NumberFormat` from `import 'package:intl/intl.dart';`

```
NumberFormat formatter = new NumberFormat("00000000");

// The following outputs your expected output
debugPrint("123 should be ${formatter.format(123)}");
debugPrint("1243 should be ${formatter.format(1243)}");
debugPrint("123456 should be ${formatter.format(123456)}");
debugPrint("12345678 should be ${formatter.format(12345678)}");
```

Result:

```
123 should be 00000123
1243 should be 00001243
123456 should be 00123456
12345678 should be 12345678
```