# I am having problem when i am trying to assign String data to Integer variable

Tags: flutter

```
String showYear;
  String showMonth;
  String showDay;
  int showDayIntVersion;

  Future getNepaliDate() async {
    NepaliDateTime _selectedDateTime = await picker.showAdaptiveDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: NepaliDateTime.now(),
        firstDate: NepaliDateTime(2000),
        lastDate: NepaliDateTime.now()
    );
    setState(() {
      showYear = DateFormat("yyyy").format(DateTime.parse(_selectedDateTime.toString()));
      showMonth = DateFormat("MM").format(DateTime.parse(_selectedDateTime.toString()));
      showDay =DateFormat("dd").format(DateTime.parse(_selectedDateTime.toString()));
        showDayIntVersion= int.parse(showDay);
     
    });
  }
```

#in my showYear i get 2022, in showMonth i get 04 and in showDay i get 02 but when i assign showDay to showDayIntVersion i only get 2 and due to it gives invalid date format day dateTime format and i have my reasons to assign showDay to showDayIntVersion need help thanks

Comment: Nothing in this code snippet can cause "invalid date format day dateTime format" or whatever you mean by that. Parsing "02" into an int will obviously give you a 2. What are you trying to do with the 2 that causes the error?

Comment: the thing is i have an icon button when i press it i want to decrease showDay by one but it is in string i cant do it on it so i had to assign showDay data to integer variable that is showDayIntVersion and in showDayIntVersion i want the day informat of 02 not only 2

Comment: Integer values cannot have leading 0's. You'll have to manually concatenate a "0" string to the front of `showDayIntVersion` if it is less than 10.

Comment: i tried to concatenate inside a condition like this but i get error saying invalid format at index 1 showDayIntVersion= 0+int.parse("")+int.parse(showDay);

Comment: Please update your question with the relevant code snippet that contains the problem instead of posting it in a comment. Also post the error stack trace. And like I said, it is impossible for `showDayIntVersion` to have a leading 0. You should be using a String variable instead. That aside, does `int.parse("")` even work? I suspect that is the cause of the problem.

Comment: Attempting to add 0 to a number won't do anything meaningful. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35245361/add-leading-zeroes-to-number-in-dart, using [String.padLeft](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.2/dart-core/String/padLeft.html).

Comment: ok as u said i have tried all things like  showDayIntVersion = int.parse(showDay.padLeft(2,"0")); inside my condition but problem is showDayIntVersion is integer and showDay is String and withour int.parse i cant assign it and due to it the problem is still the same

Comment: Okay, well, as others have mentioned here, the code you have included won't be giving you the "invalid date format" error, so you'll likely need to show the code where you are attempting to parse the string created from the incremented `showDayIntVersion`.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to show string as int then do like this:

```
int.parse(showday);
```

Comment: yes i did that but it doesnt solve my problem i want to get 02,03 format but when i do int.parse(showday) then only 2 is assign to showDayIntVersion and i want to assign 02 integer not only 2

Comment: for add lading 0 you can add like this print(3.toString().padLeft(2, '0')); like this